# Using =averageifs with multiple text criteria in different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm busy with creating an spreadsheet where I can get the average price of holidaydeals with a specific tag (f.e. a destination). When I do this for only one tag column the formula is working :) :

```
=averageifs(C4:C10,E4:E10,L1,F4:F10,"Frankrijk vakantie")
```

But... I have more then 10 tag columns in total and in every column something like "Frankrijk vakantie" could be found. My simple mind thought, okay lets change F4:F10 (in this example) to F4:G10 to look for "Frankrijk vakantie" in two columns. But... the formula didn't work.

Link to spreadsheet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gw5VC5qT1bzbFIPBu5j4dLXBmJjh7GuW/view?usp=sharing

I've also added a screenshot. I hope that someone can help me with this. Would be great, thank you!

[image: Screenshot of spreadsheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In L2 try

```
=query({C4:C11, ArrayFormula(N(mmult(N(F4:O11="Frankrijk vakantie"), transpose(column(F3:O3)^0))>0))}, "Select AVG(Col1) where Col2 > 0 label AVG(Col1) '' ")
```

and see if that works?

EDIT: to include a month/year filter try

```
=query({C4:C11, ArrayFormula(N(mmult(N( (F4:O11="Frankrijk vakantie")*(E4:E11=L1)), transpose(column(F3:O3)^0))>0))}, "Select AVG(Col1) where Col2 > 0 label AVG(Col1) '' ")
```

The formula makes use of a virtual array, containing the values of column C and the output of the mmult() function. The latter creates a column with 1's if 'Franrkijk vakantie' is found in that row AND the date in column E matches the date in L1. The query then averages the values from column C and filters out the rows where the conditions of the MMULT() are not met.

EDIT 2: To check for a 'double match' in the row, try

```
=query({C4:E11, transpose(query(transpose(F4:S11),,9^99))}, "Select AVG(Col1) where Col3='"&L1&"' and Col4 contains 'Frankrijk vakantie' and Col4 contains 'Europa vakantie' label AVG(Col1)''", 0)
```

Change range to suit.

Comment: Wow, thank you that works. Great! I try to understand it but it looks very difficult. I think I have to read some more about ArrayFormulas. Thank you so much! //

**One more question, in this example you don't see different dates but in the main file there is also data from july june and other years. How can I include this in the formula? That if L2 is 'july2020' he will get the data only from the deals from july 2020.**

Comment: You should be able to incorporate that in the MMULT(). See updated answer.

Comment: Nice! That's great thanks! Now I was just trying to extend this formula to 'filter' on two tags. So beside 'Frankrijk vakantie' also 'Europa vakantie'. I tried to implement another segment in the formula but it doesnt work. Do you know if it is possible at all? || I tried this: `=query({$C$4:$C10, ArrayFormula(N(mmult(N( ($F$4:$G10="Frankrijk vakantie")*(F4:G10="Herfstvakantie")*($E$4:$E10=L1)), transpose(column($F$3:$G$3)^0))>0))}, "Select AVG(Col1) where Col2 > 0 label AVG(Col1) '' ")` but it gives as answer: *Query completed with an empty output.*

Comment: Try =query({C4:C11, ArrayFormula(--(mmult( --(((F4:O11="Frankrijk vakantie")+(F4:O11="Europa vakantie"))*(E4:E11=L1)), transpose(column(F3:O3)^0))>0))}, "Select AVG(Col1) where Col2 > 0 label AVG(Col1) '' ")

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The ony thing is that it shouldn't be Frankrijk or Europa vakantie but it should only return the average value if both tags are located in that row. So if tag 1 is Frankrijk vakantie and tag 2 is Europa vakantie (in a row) than it should count the value (C) in the total average. If, for example I look for Frankrijk vakantie and Bali vakantie and there is no row with two of those tags than it should not count the value of that row in column C. Thats why I thought about an AND function but thats not the solution I guess... :)

Comment: In that case, check out the last formula I added to my answer and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works! Cool to see that there is way more possible with sheets than I thought. Thank you!